# How do I use rule based Task Generator Target to output inside the source directory in Waf?

Tags: python, build-system, waf

I have my wscript file as:-

```
def build(bld):

    bld(
        rule = 'cp ${SRC} ${TGT}',
        source = 'a.txt',
        target = 'b.txt',
    )
```

By default, the output target is created inside the build directory `build/b.txt`,
However, I want my target to be created inside the source directory where my current wscript file is.
One method I tried is :-

```
def build(bld):

    bld(
        rule = 'cp ${SRC} b.txt',
        source = 'a.txt',
        cwd = './',
    )
```

This outputs `b.txt` inside the source directory relative to the current wscript file however the problem I face is that I lose the automatic dependency calculation or rebuilding as I'm not providing the target.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a way how to do so.
What we can do is pass the node object to the target.

```
def build(bld):

    bld(
        rule = 'cp ${SRC} ${TGT}',
        source = 'a.txt',
        target = bld.path.make_node('/path_you_want/b.txt')
    )
```